# Compare specific sections from two different files

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

I am on Linux and I have two files a.txt and b.txt that I would like to compare. However there is a catch.

1. I know for a fact the the first few lines of both files are different and I don't care about the first few differences (They are irrelevant).
2. I would like to make sure that after the first few lines, everything else is matching just fine.

I already looked up the command `diff` and it didn't have an option that would clip the comparison to specific sections

Comment: Have you actually tried using diff on your files? It usually syncs OK if there is substantial commonality in the files but various differences at the start. You might want to tell it to ignore whitespace though with -w. Obviously you will be shown the differences in the file headers but if the code is mostly the same then it will say so.

Comment: The problem is the files are not that big (~50 lines). In other words, 15 lines are a big chunk of the files, so that is why diff is not giving me an OK. Nevertheless, I still would like to ignore the first 10-15 lines

Comment: Maybe something like `diff <(tail -n 35 a.txt) <(tail -n 35 b.txt)` ?